# How to chop down trees

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I have a flimsy axe and a Nook Miles+ task of chopping down a tree but it doesn't appear that I can do so. Do I need to eat lots of fruit or is this just impossible until I get the axe upgrade? What's the easiest way to do the latter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flimsy and Stone axe cannot chop trees, only the Axe or higher grade is able to. Flimsy and stone is used to collect logs, Regular axe is used for clearing.